# Python-django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, wagtail

In existing wagtail project I run `python3 manage.py makemigrations` but this gives this issue

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration 'collection-name' dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('wagtailcore', '0029_unicode_slugfield_dj19')**
```

If I hide wagtailcore dependencies from that particular collection,then I am getting other wagtail dependancies error(like wagtail images), so I think this issue related to wagtail.

Answer (score 2):

You must have deleted some migration file before running this command.

One solution is that undo that deleted migration file.

2nd solution is that delete all migration file in migration folder and then hit command

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations
```

Hopefully this will resolve your issue!